# Immediate address transfer inconsistently SPLINT

Tags: c, splint

I have a code segment here, but SPLINT is giving me a warning here

```
"tcpuip\dhcpc\dhcpc.c: (in function send_discover)
tcpuip\dhcpc\dhcpc.c(219,21): Immediate address &m->options[4] passed as only
                                 param: add_msg_type (&m->options[4], ...)
  An immediate address (result of & operator) is transferred inconsistently.
  (Use -immediatetrans to inhibit warning)
"
```

```
    static void send_discover(void)
    {
            u8_t *end;
            struct dhcp_msg *m = (struct dhcp_msg *)uip_appdata;
```

```
        create_msg(m);

        end = add_msg_type(&m->options[4], DHCPDISCOVER);   //line 219
        end = add_req_options(end);
        end = add_end(end);  

        uip_send(uip_appdata, end - (u8_t *)uip_appdata);
}
```

I am trying to work around this problem, please anyone can through some light on it. I have been googling for like 3 hrs, hav'nt found a soln.

Comment: What is the prototype of `add_msg_type`? Have you tried `m->options + 4` instead?

Comment: Is the `options` field of `struct dhcp_msg` defined as a VLA?

Comment: thanks Joachim Pileborg and Michael Foukarakis, i solved the problem.

Comment: and what was the problem?